# Datatables - Search Box outside datatable

Tags: jquery, search, datatables, filtering

I'm using DataTables ([datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net)) and I would like my search box to be outside of the table (for example in my header div).

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can use the DataTables api to filter the table. So all you need is your own input field with a keyup event that triggers the filter function to DataTables. With css or jquery you can hide/remove the existing search input field. Or maybe DataTables has a setting to remove/not-include it.

Checkout the Datatables API documentation on this.

Example:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myInputTextField">
```

JS

```
oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();   //pay attention to capital D, which is mandatory to retrieve "api" datatables' object, as @Lionel said
$('#myInputTextField').keyup(function(){
      oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})
```

Comment: You should definitely use .keyup instead of .keypress, otherwise you'll experience a delay in results

Comment: I messed with putting `$(".dataTables_filter :input").focus().val(value).keypress();` in the `keyup` on my input for about an hour, before finding this. Never though to use the API.. Elegant solution!

Comment: The JS needs to change to use .search( $(this).val() ).draw() in place of fnFilter. See: https://datatables.net/manual/api#Chaining I changed this answer to fix it, but it appears it needs to be peer reviewed first.

Comment: Remark: You will still need the "searching: true" option, and then you probably want to hide the default searchbox so just set the sDOM option to null.

Comment: ...or to the correct format of your choice of course :) More info : http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Comment: Instantiating $().dataTable() with a small "d" will return a jQuery object rather than a DataTables API instance. The latter can be achieved by calling "oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();" with a capital "D". This is required to be able to call .search on it (if will throw a "function undefined" error otherwise). See: https://www.datatables.net/faqs/#api

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504608/use-search-bar-to-filter-data-in-data-table-based-on-search-string?noredirect=1#comment68443393_40504608

Can anyone have a check on this?

Comment: And to keep the full search functionality, the search string needs to be displayed after refresh in the custon input. This line do the job for me: `$('#myInputTextField').val(oTable.search());`

Comment: @netbrain I have the same problem but your solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @netbrain My code js file link is here http://pastebin.com/SDe3wCPf. I always get no records when i start typing in my input field.

Comment: @prabu try adding the searching: true option.

Comment: Search was not working for me. But when I changed $('#myTable').dataTable();  to $('#myTable').DataTable(); it started working

Comment: Thank you for this answer - saved me some time looking through the docs. For my use with the Angular JS version of this library - you can use an implementation like so: vm.dtInstance.DataTable.search(event.value).draw();

Comment: is this applicable for server side?

Answer (score 39):

As per @lvkz comment :

if you are using datatable with uppercase d `.DataTable()` ( this will return a Datatable API object ) use this :

```
 oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
```

which is @netbrain answer.

if you are using datatable with lowercase d `.dataTable()` ( this will return a jquery object )  use this :

```
 oTable.fnFilter($(this).val());
```

Comment: `oTable.fnFilter($(this).val());` Worked for me too,

Comment: Both methods are valid, depending on how are you calling the datatable:
` oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;` you use when you call it: `.DataTable()`
and this one: 
`oTable.fnFilter($(this).val());` when you use `.dataTable()`

The difference is at the capital D. Hope it helps!

Comment: Gives a "oTable.fnFilter is not a function" error for datatables version 1.10.5

Comment: Just figured that with jQuery you can also access Database API like this :
`oTable.api().search($(this).val()).draw();`
It can be useful, especially if you want manual control over pagination `length` as well :
`oTable.api().page.len($(this).val()).draw();`

Answer (score 18):

For recent and new version of DataTables, You should follow these steps:

1- `searching` option must be `true`.

2- Hide default search input:

```
.dataTables_filter {
    display: none;
}
```

3- Add new search input:

```
<input type="text" id="search">
```

4- Request search:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var table = $('.table-meetups').DataTable();
    table.search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`sDom`](http://www.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom) option for this.

**Default with search input in its own div:**

```
sDom: '<"search-box"r>lftip'
```

**If you use jQuery UI** (`bjQueryUI` set to `true`):

```
sDom: '<"search-box"r><"H"lf>t<"F"ip>'
```

The above will put the search/filtering `input` element into it's own `div` with a class named `search-box` that is outside of the actual table.

Even though it uses its special shorthand syntax it can actually take any HTML you throw at it.

Comment: @Marcus: actually I feel that sDom is not quite elegant to use, put aside the fact that we can't fully customize the search box (there's a hardcode "Search" text in that box).

Comment: but its still inside div.datatables_Wrapper, any way to move it outside of it as well ?

Comment: @Artur79 Sadly no. Not without hacking the source of Datatables, at least.

Comment: <333 this syntax `'<"search-box"r><"H"lf>t<"F"ip>'` not sure if something worse exists

Comment: @HoàngLong you actually can customise the search box using options like this: `language: { search: "example", searchPlaceholder: "example" }`

Answer (score 10):

This one helped me for DataTables Version 1.10.4, because its new API

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();    
$('#myInputTextField').keyup(function(){
   oTable.search( $(this).val() ).draw();
})
```

Comment: Note the capital "D" of "var oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();" (https://www.datatables.net/faqs/#api)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

I tried all alternatives posted, but no work, I used a way that is not right but it worked perfectly.

Example search input

```
<input id="searchInput" type="text">
```

the jquery code

```
$('#listingData').dataTable({
  responsive: true,
  "bFilter": true // show search input
});
$("#listingData_filter").addClass("hidden"); // hidden search input

$("#searchInput").on("input", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#listingData').DataTable().search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint of hiding search input  and "input" event. But mind you, you are instantiating another DataTable inside .on("input".

Answer (score 7):

More recent versions have a different syntax:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on('keyup change', function () {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
});
```

Note that this example uses the variable `table` assigned when datatables is first initialised. If you don't have this variable available, simply use:

```js
var table = $('#example').dataTable().api();

// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on('keyup change', function () {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
});
```

Since: DataTables 1.10

– Source: https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Answer (score 5):

I want to add one more thing to the [@netbrain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5990528/756261) relevant in case you use server-side processing (see [serverSide](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) option).

Query throttling performed by default by datatables (see [searchDelay](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchDelay) option) does not apply to the `.search()` API call. You can get it back by using [$.fn.dataTable.util.throttle()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.util.throttle()) in the following way:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
var search = $.fn.dataTable.util.throttle(
    function(val) {
        table.search(val).draw();
    },
    400  // Search delay in ms
);

$('#mySearchBox').keyup(function() {
    search(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be work for you:(DataTables 1.10.7)

```
oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();

$('#myInputTextField').on('keyup change', function(){
  oTable.api().search($(this).val()).draw();
})
```

or

```
oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();

$('#myInputTextField').on('keyup change', function(){
  oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the div when the table is drawn using the `fnDrawCallback` function.

```
    $("#myTable").dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        $(".dataTables_filter").each(function () {
            $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().siblings(".panel-body"));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Or if you use a newer version of datatable you will have: `"drawCallback": function (settings) {
               $(".dataTables_filter").each(function () {
            $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().siblings(".panel-body"));
        });
            },`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   "bProcessing": true,
   "bServerSide": true,
   "sAjaxSource": "../admin/ajax/loadtransajax.php",
   "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        // Initialize your variables here
        // I have assign the textbox value for "text_min_val"
        var min_val = $("#min").val();  //push to the aoData
        aoData.push({name: "text_min_val", value:min_val});
   },
   "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
       $(nRow).attr('id', 'tr_' + aData[0]);
       $(nRow).attr('name', 'tr_' + aData[0]);
       $(nRow).attr('min', 'tr_' + aData[0]); 
       $(nRow).attr('max', 'tr_' + aData[0]); 
   }
});
```

In `loadtransajax.php` you may receive the get value:

```
if ($_GET['text_min_val']){
    $sWhere = "WHERE ("; 
    $sWhere .= " t_group_no LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['text_min_val']) . "%' ";
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery dataTable so you need to just add `"bFilter":true`. This will display default search box outside table and its works dynamically..as per expected

```
$("#archivedAssignments").dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bFilter":true,
                "sPageFirst": false,
                "sPageLast": false,
                "oLanguage": {
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "<< previous",
                    "sNext" : "Next >>",
                    "sFirst": "<<",
                    "sLast": ">>"
                    }
                },
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bInfo":false,
            "bSortable":true
        });
```

Comment: The question was to change the position of the dynamically created . Putting it OUTSIDE the table