# Jquery Datatable search box reposition

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I want to re position filter box in out of the jquery data table. I want to exactly like this:

[image]

How should I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just relocate the `#<table_id>_filter` div to the desired position with `detach().appendTo()` like this :

```js
$("#example").DataTable({
    initComplete : function() {
        $("#example_filter").detach().appendTo('#new-search-area');
    }
});
```

you can even style how the search filter box should appear in the relocated position :

```css
#new-search-area {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#new-search-area input {
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dq2bmgd9/**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataTables api to filter the table. So all you need is your own input field with a keyup event that triggers the filter function to DataTables. With css or jquery you can hide/remove the existing search input field. Or maybe DataTables has a setting to remove/not-include it.

Checkout the Datatables API documentation on this.

Example:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myInputTextField">
```

JS

```
oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
$('#myInputTextField').keyup(function(){
      oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})
```

original source [Datatables - Search Box outside datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990386/datatables-search-box-outside-datatable/5990528#5990528)