# MVC jquery datatable search from external input

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to set an external input to search a jquery datatable.  Please see my view code:

```
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/select.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
    .ready(function() {
        var sfTable = $('#sfTable')
            .dataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Search/LoadData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Address", "autoWidth": true }
                ],
                "searching": true,
                "select": true
            });

        $('#searchMe')
            .on('keyup',
                function() {
                    sfTable.search(this.value).draw();
                });
    });
</script>
<input id="searchMe" type="text"/>
<table id="sfTable" class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

If I use the default searching in the rendered datatable it works fine, but using my custom `SearchMe` control doesn't search the table.  My final goal is to have two datatables which are searched from a single input.

Comment: Here You have! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990386/datatables-search-box-outside-datatable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

[Datatables - Search Box outside datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990386/datatables-search-box-outside-datatable)

This led me to the answer, and it was really simple - the `var sfTable = $('#sfTable').dataTable({` code had to be a capital D on DataTable() - suddenly it works!