# How to add search functionality in dataTables?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatable

I'm trying to add search functionality in the dataTable.

I have tried doing the "searching" option to true and adding 'bs-select' class. Still, it doesn't work!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#program_table').DataTable({
   "searching": true
   });

  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
```

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/helloIndia/2nary46x/1/

Comment: search is enabled in DataTables by default.   What happens when you type something in to the search box?  Are you using the server side attribute (in which case, you'd need to implement search on the server side)

Comment: Yes, Search is enabled by default but it doesn't seem to work in this case.
There is no output after typing something in the Search box.
No, it's a static table
[https://jsfiddle.net/helloIndia/2nary46x/1/]

Comment: It's not working because the input box isn't the one that comes with DataTables.  If you implement your own input, you also need to handle the search yourself.  I've removed your extra code so that datatables is using its native search input, and it works fine here:  https://jsfiddle.net/mtv0Lk9q/

Comment: If you remove `dom: "tplis",` , you'll see the native datatables search box...

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Is there a way to implement the search functionality with the different input box?

Comment: Yes.  Google is your friend!  Here's one thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990386/datatables-search-box-outside-datatable

Comment: It's working!!
Thanks @devlincarnate )

Comment: @devlincarnate 1 more issue. How can we export data as CSV using the HTML export button?
I have updated the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/helloIndia/2nary46x/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really liked **@devlincarnate** answer. It was very helpful.

But you can also implement individual column search. Just like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
 
    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;
 
                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }
    });
    
    $('#example tfoot tr').appendTo('#example thead');
});
```

```css
/*tfoot {
      display: table-header-group;
  }*/
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sydney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Fiona Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Shou Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sydney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Shad Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Note: If you prefer having the search boxes in the **footer** section instead of the **header**, just remove this line:

```
$('#example tfoot tr').appendTo('#example thead');
```

More info: **[Individual column searching (text inputs)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter)**