# Move Datatables Filter and Other Options to other Positions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I want to position the filter bar and other elements from my [datatables](https://datatables.net/) table to a complete other part of my page. In particular, I'd like to move the search filter bar to the section titled 'filters' - and in the process, learn how to move any of these elements. However,  I can't seem to figure out how to do it and have only had luck moving them to the top and bottom of the table. I've tried with `getElementById` but had no luck.

This is a simple example code, but please note that I am using a Flask app which draws data in via python and the actual datatable itself is a bit more complicated.

**HTML**

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">
  I have a bunch of filters sitting on the left here and want to move some parts from the datatable here.
</div>
<div class="main">
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
          </script>
```

**CSS**

```
.filters {
    position: fixed;
    width: 34%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 66%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 34%;
    top: 10%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

**Desired Result**
[image]

Comment: Focusing on the core of your queston: To place the search field wherever you want, you can create your own input field for this. See [Search Box outside datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5990528/12567365) - but also bear in mind that you will need to hide the default search input field using the DataTables [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option - so, something like `dom: 'lrtip'` - where the `f` option for "filtering" has been removed. The `dom` option gives you the ability to move and style the other controls also - to a limited degree, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

You can add an input into the HTML, then call that input and use the following,

```
$('#searchInput').keyup(function () {
            oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
        });
```

Full solution:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<div class="filters">


    <!-- SOLUTION PART 1 -->
    <form class="form">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" class="form-control" placeholder="&#xf002;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search">
        </div>
    </form>


</div>
<div class="main">
    <table id="example" class="example" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<script>
    // SOLUTION PART 2
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
            "pagingType": "simple",
            "ordering": "false",
            "dom": '<<t>ip>'
        });
        $('#searchInput').keyup(function () {
            oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
        });

    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.filters {
    position: fixed;
    width: 34%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 66%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 34%;
    top: 10%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```